# Energy absorbed by the gas from a PV-diagram

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws

> 10. The $PV$-graph for a monoatomic gas is shown in the figure. Find the energy absorbed by the gas during this process.
>
> [image]

I’m having trouble with this question because both pressure and volume are changing and I cannot calculate a value for $T$. So far, I ended up with an answer using the ratio of $C_p$ and $C_v$, and got $6.25P_0V_0$. The answer is $8.5P_0V_0$.

Comment: Using the equation you learned for calculating the amount of work, how much work is done on the surroundings n this process?  From the ideal gas law, what is the change in temperature in this process?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you forgot to take the work done by the gas into account. From [the first law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics):

$$Q = \Delta U - W \label{eq:1}\tag{1}$$

For the monoatomic gas $U=\frac{3}{2}PV$, so

$$\Delta U = U_2 - U_1 = \frac{3}{2}(P_2V_2 - P_1V_1) = \frac{3}{2}(3P_0 \cdot 2V_0 - 2P_0 \cdot V_0) = 6P_0V_0 \tag{2}$$

On the other hand, since the gas expanded ($V_2 > V_1$), the work is negative and can be found geometrically as the area under the line:

[image]

$$W = -(\color{blue}{2P_0(2V_0-V_0)} + \color{orange}{0.5 \cdot (3P_0 - 2P_0)(2V_0 - V_0)}) = -2.5P_0V_0 \tag{3}$$

Now back to \eqref{eq:1}:

$$Q = 6P_0V_0 -(-2.5P_0V_0) = 8.5P_0V_0$$

Comment: @Sanjana No prob:) Try to understand the concepts behind these problems, in reality they are all quite similar.

Comment: I actually interpreted "energy absorbed" to mean $\Delta U$. Obviously, the answer shows that I was wrong. Was there a reason why you interpreted it to be $q$?

Comment: @orthocresol Same here. I did the math for $\Delta U$ and realized that's not what the author expects from the reader:)